# How to name columns in a netcdf file?

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf4

How is it possible to name columns in a netcdf file using python ?

I use such a syntax :

```
with Dataset(file_name, 'w', format=NETCDF_FORMAT) as ncfile:
   ncfile.createDimension('Time', 12)
   ncfile.createDimension('Simulations', 15)
   ncfile.createVariable('Asset_value', values, ('Simulations', 'Time'))
```

I would like to put each month of the year as name of each column, instead of 0, 1, 2, ... that netcdf provides.

Is there a way to do it in python ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you consider to be a 'column' in a netcdf file? If, like in your example, you have a variable 'Asset_value', you can well call it by it's 'name'?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
To clarify, I called 'column' each values of Asset_value with Time = 0, for example because Time is the second dimension.
I would also call row each 'line' obtained for Simulations = 12 for example.
What I want is to name my axis of Time with month of years. Is it clearer ?

Answer (score 1):

If I get that correctly, what you want to do is store a [compound data type](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/data_type.html#types_compound_types) in netcdf format. What you could do if you use nc version 4 is simply drop a `dict` into a `group`:

```py
from netCDF4 import Dataset

# suppose you have data in the form of a dict:
input = {'some key': 'somevalue'}
with Dataset('your_ncfile.nc', 'w') as f:
    data = f.createGroup('Data')
    for k, v in input.items():
        setattr(data, k, v)
```

I found this pretty convenient since `dict` nicely fits into the HDF5 data model (basis of netcdf4) and can equally well be "loaded back" into Python. To get the data "back out":

```py
with Dataset('your_ncfile.nc') as f:
    Data_Out = {}
    dataOut = f.groups['Data']
    for attr in dataOut.ncattrs():
        Data_Out[attr] = dataOut.getncattr(attr)
```

Note: 1) I didn't check so far if this also works e.g. with a pd.df. 2) Your collegues might get upset if you're the only one using nc4 while everybody else uses nc3. nc4 features might not work with tools written for nc3 ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
Don't worry, my colleagues also use nc4 ;) However, my values are stored in a pd.df and I don't manage to make your solution working :(

Comment: @Benito yeah I thought so... df to dict (and back) might be a hack here but not really elegant. The other option I see is store the df as a 2D array and create an additional variable that holds the column names etc.